# System.out.println в сервлете

Tags: java

Привет,возникли проблемы с кодом,вот вам один из методов сервлета:

```
static <T> String paginate (List<T> pages, int pagesPerOut)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i += pagesPerOut) {
            System.out.println(paginate(pages, i, pagesPerOut));
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Но ведь это сервлет тут так писать нельзя,вот как можно решить данную проблему?
Вот весь код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class servletss extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        File file = new File("C:\\prov\\");
        String list[] = file.list();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>testservlets</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        /*
         * начало вывода
         */
        ArrayList<String> sizel = new ArrayList<String>();
        sizel = pagef();
        int sizelist;
        sizelist = sizel.size();
        int pageint = 1;// номер страницы
        ArrayList<String> sizetris = new ArrayList<String>();
        int startlist = (pageint - 1) * 30;
        int endlist = (sizel.size() >= (startlist + 30)) ? (startlist + 30)
                : sizel.size();
        sizetris.addAll(sizel.subList(startlist, endlist));
        double startdouble = 10.0;// конец показа страниц
        int endint = (int) (pageint * 10);// конечное число пользователя
        double allpage = sizelist / 3;// число страниц всего
        double page = allpage / startdouble;// деление страниц
        double lsc = Math.ceil(page);
        String separator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        if (endint > lsc * 10) {
            out.println("страниц не найдено");
        } else {
            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");
            out.println("<div class=\"bloctext\">"
                    + paginate(sizetris, endint * 3) + separator + "</div>");
            out.println("<div class=\"pagen\">" + pageint + "</div>");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            out.println("<a href=\"http://localhost:8080/test/servletss?i=" + i
                    + "\" str=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
        }

    static <T> String paginate (List<T> pages, int pagesPerOut)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i += pagesPerOut) {
            System.out.println(paginate(pages, i, pagesPerOut));
        }
        return "";
    }

    static <T> List<T> paginate (List<T> pages, int start, int count)
    {
        int end = start + count > pages.size() ? pages.size() : start + count;
        return pages.subList(start, end);
    }

    /*
     * метод для возвращения массива страниц
     */
    static ArrayList<String> pagef ()
    {
        ArrayList<String> page = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String s = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\prov\\");
        String list[] = file.list();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                File fileread = new File("C:\\prov\\" + list[i]);
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(fileread), "UTF-8"));
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    page.add(s + "\n");
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return page;
    }

}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? В любом Java-приложении можно использовать System.out, в том числе и в сервлете. Или вас смущает то, что то, что вы пишете в System.out не попадает на страницу? Так оно и не должно. Нужно писать в OutputStream или Writer, полученные из HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream() (или HttpServletResponse.getWriter()), как вы делаете в методе doGet(). А вообще, писать в OutputStream из сервлета хорошо только если вы пишете что-то небольшое, например, JSON-ответ на AJAX-запрос. Обычно код страницы хранят отдельно от сервлета. Посмотрите в сторону технологии JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out` действительно в сервлете бессмыслен. Нормальные пацаны используют логгинг (`java.util.logging` встроенный в JDK), либо (что более правильно) [Apache Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)